# How do I create a scrolling background?

Tags: java, graphics, game-physics

I am a teenager trying to create a simple top-down game in java for my own enjoyment. A few months ago I was working on said game and ran into a roadblock. I couldn't figure out how to create a background that scrolled as the character moved. I managed to create a background that moved, but it behaved strangely when the character moved. I eventually got frustrated and took a hiatus from programming until I got motivated to start again.

I would appreciate if somebody could help explain to me what I need to do to create a scrolling background in layman's terms (some example code would be nice too)

Also if somebody could explain to me how to make the background start following the character a moment after the character starts moving that would be wonderful, I'm led to believe that most games do that to make the scrolling feel more natural.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: The question is too open. Completely depends on what technology you're using. E.g. if you're using some sort of game engine, graphics library etc..

Comment: Also, do you have any code that you have tried? Please refer to the help center on how to write a valid question.

Comment: @m_callens Not quite... there seems to be a need for some heavy work done in `paintComponent` here, not a ScrollPane

Comment: I know this says Java but I think it is more about game development. Take a look at https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation

Answer (score 3):

I recommend learning about different Java libraries such as JFrame and JComponent. I made a top-down game myself in Java for the learning experience and enjoyment, much like yourself. While you can use game engines like Unity, or GameMaker, to help you make a game more easily, it is fully possible to make a great game using only Java, although you might have to do some more learning if you chose to do so - I personally loved learning about Java though. Here is some code snippet of how to create a JFrame:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(500, 500); // width, height
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setTitle("Game Title");
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setResizable(false);
```

The JFrame is like a "canvas", where you can draw things, I personally chose to make different scenes of my game JComponents, which I added to the main JFrame. If you want to know more about how I made my game with these principles check it out on GitHub, or feel free to ask more questions: https://github.com/danielgalvaoguerra/Prallax---Java-Top-Down-Shooter

Hope this helps you get started!

Answer (score 1):

As for every game out there that has a 2- or 3-dimensional world in order to move the camera you need to move the entire world.

So if you want a scrolling background you draw your character in the middle of your screen while you move the whole world in the opposite direction your character is running.

And in order to create a scrolling effect so that your background scrolls after your character moved a bit you would simply specify a distance your character has to move in order to start scrolling. Just check if he has moved more than your specified distance and then move the world accordingly.